# In command prompt, able to compile a java file from different directory but not able to run it

Tags: java

I saved my java file in `d:\Vnew`.

Compiled it from other folder(`C:\>javac d:\Vnew\Vsimple.java`) in command prompt which works fine.

But when I try to run (`C:\>java d:\Vnew\Vsimple`),getting below error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class d:\Vnew\Vsimple
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: d:\Vnew\Vsimple

Note: If I run from same folder, `d:\Vnew`, it works fine.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JVM about d:\Vnew path at compile time only. While running the MainClass, he doesn’t know that there is a class Vsimple in different directory
Try to execute with -cp option

C:>java -cp d:\Vnew\; Vsimple